# How can I customize the_content(); output?

Tags: the-content

I want to customize every image or p of the_content(); output, assign class and so on..
What I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a filter to the content directly on functions.php and use str_replace or perhaps some preg_replace (regex) to change the output of the content. Not tested. Try something like this:

```
function add_class_to_img_and_p_in_content($content) {

   $pattern ="/<img(.*?)class=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)>/i";
   $replacement = '<img$1class="$2 newclass newclasstwo"$3>';

   $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);

   $pattern ="/<p(.*?)class=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)>/i";
   $replacement = '<p$1class="$2 newclass newclasstwo"$3>';

   $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);


   return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_class_to_img_and_p_in_content',11);
```

If your p and img tags do not already have a class attribute you can simply do:

```
function new_content($content) {

    $content = str_replace('<img','<img class="newImgclass"', $content);
    $content = str_replace('<p>','<p class="newPclass">', $content);

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content','new_content');
```

Comment: thanks
it works for <p>, but not with img

Comment: sorry, thats because I closed the img tag, when infact it never closes without atleast the src attribute. I will edit my answer.

Comment: thanks, now it works,
but it replaces all the wordpress classes with the new one.
If I want to add my new class to the others?

Comment: edited my answer so you can add newclass to the elements that already have class atribute.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can modify the img. I just want you know that the second part of the fuction (for <p>) applies the rule fot the img, I think something is wrong.

I never see a function like this in other themes, and they customize the_content output, do you know how they get it?